# Add column/content inside menu

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way to insert a content element or the contents of a column into the menu?

I want the menu dropdown to contain it's sub-pages, as normal, but also have a featured area that can be edited on occasion.

Eg. the menu Item 'Fruit' will list sub pages "Apple, Banana, Orange" but then after those have a featured picture like say a Banana with a bit of info under it. Then next month edit the feature to be an Apple.

If it was only a picture I could use the page resources tab, but I require some text as well...

Comment: How are you building your menu? TypoScript, fluid, something else?

Comment: @Jost I am using a standard Typoscript menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your TypoScript setup, use an appropriate [`stdWrap`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap)-enabled property. There are `stdWrap`, `stdWrap2` and many other properties that have `stdWrap` enabled. On those, you can use `cObject`, `preCObject`, `postCObject` and probably some more to insert arbitrary TypoScript content objects, including a [`CONTENT`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) object to fetch the content. If you want to fetch the content element with ID `42` located on page with ID `276`, the `CONTENT` object would look like this (x being the property of stdWrap that takes a cObject, e.g. `stdWrap.preCObject`):

```
x = CONTENT
x {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        uidInList = 42
        pidInList = 276
        languageField = sys_language_uid
    }
    renderObj {
        // Insert rendering definition for the content object here,
        // or leave the entire property renderObj out if you want the
        // global rendering definition
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! 2 questions: 1) Instead of a specific pid can I use the current pid? 2) Instead of a specific content element can I have a whole column?

Comment: Yes, for the current PID you can use `this` as value for the PID. But it'll probably not work for a menu, since that's the PID of the page you are currently viewing/rendering. For rendering a complete column, remove the `uidInList` property, and add a `where`-property with a query for the column (`colPos = <yourcolumnnumber>`). Also check the [docs of the `select`-property](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html).

Comment: You're right, it works only for the page you're viewing. Is there a way to maybe set {field:uid} to a variable, then set pidInList to that variable?

Comment: Yes, `pidInList` supports `stdWrap`, so you can insert basically anything in there. E.g. to read the value from the TypoScript constant `menuContentPid`: `pidInList.data = {$menuContentPid}`. To use the uid of the current record (which should be the page you are currently rendering in the menu, but not sure), you could use `pidInList.field = uid`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! In my case I ended up using `pidInList.field = pid`

Comment: That should be the parent page of the page you are currently rendering the menu item for - is this  the thing you intend to do?

Comment: Yes, the feature content is on the parent page and is rendered as a child of that page in the menu.